# Can't create C++ console application in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I downloaded Visual Studio 2013 from official site. But I can't create a new console project, as I've seen in some tutorials. The reason is that there is no console application in templates for C++.

[image]

May be there is another way to create a new console application?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's Visual Studio Express for Windows, which is used for Windows Store and Windows Phone apps.

To do Windows desktop apps you need **[Visual Studio Express for Windows Desktop](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=43733)**.

Or, of course, you can use e.g. the MinGW g++ compiler, and some general IDE such as Code::Blocks or Eclipse. But Microsoft's help system is very useful. And currently g++ only supports the Windows API as it was with Windows XP, no newer stuff.

Comment: Thank you. I usually use MinGW + Sublime Text 2 as an "IDE". But now I want to create applications (not single files).

Comment: @klimenkov : Your original toolchain does not prevent you from generating applications from multiple sources.  There are many arguments for using VS, but that alone is not a compelling one.  You can continue to use MInGW with Code::Blocks, Eclipse, Orwell Dev-C++, QTCreator and no doubt many others to get the *project management* features of an IDE.

Comment: I would suggest that the most compelling argument for using VS is its debugger.  Everything in its "help system" is available online via MSDN.  Its code navigation and "intellisense" features work well too (improved since previous versions, but probably responsible for long project open times).

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to create a Console project no matter what version of VS Express you are using.

1. Create any type of project (i.e. A basic "class library" project).
2. Right-click the project in Solution Explorer and click Properties. You'll see a dropdown for "Output type". Select "Console Application".
3. Create a Main method somewhere as an entry point into the app. Doesn't matter what class you put it in.

   `class Program
   {
       static void Main(string[] args)
       {
           Console.WriteLine("We made a console app");
           Console.ReadKey();
       }
   }`

I did this with "Visual Studio 2013 Express for Web", so I'm not absolutely certain what your mileage will be on other flavors.